# Graphql query variable is not updating in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, graphql

I am building a simple single-page react website that uses two API's one is rest API and the second is GraphQl using simple hooks

**What I am trying to do is:**
first fetching the anime_chan data and passing the character name that I get from anime_chan data to GraphQl query `search` variable so that it gives me the data of that character

**The flow I want is -**

1. fetch rest API (anime_chan)
2. update the search variable in GraphQl query
3. fetch GraphQl API (ani_list)
4. set anime_chan_data
5. set ani_list_info

**Problem is:**
The GraphQl query `search` variable is never gets updated

**Code**

```
function App(){
const [variables, setVariables] = useState({
  search:'lelouch'
});
// I also tried this
/* var variables = {
search: 'lelouch',
} */

console.log('before: '+ variables.search);

var query = `
query($search: String) {
Character(search: $search) {
  name {
    first
  }
  image {
    large
    medium
  }
  siteUrl
  }
}`;

var ani_list_url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
  options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          query: query,
          variables: variables
      })
  };

  
const anime_chan_url = 'https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random';

const [anime_chan_data, setAnime_chan_data] = useState({
  loading:true,
  data:{},
});
const [ani_list_info, setAni_list_info] = useState({});


const get_anime_chan_Data = async() =>{
  const response = await fetch(anime_chan_url);
  const anime_chan_data = await response.json();
  console.log(anime_chan_data);
  setAnime_chan_data({
    loading:false,
    data: anime_chan_data,
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  get_anime_chan_Data();

  setVariables({
    search:anime_chan_data.character
  });

  console.log('After: '+ variables.search);

  fetch(ani_list_url, options).then(handleResponse)
                    .then(handleData)
                    .catch(handleError);

  function handleResponse(response) {
      return response.json().then(function (json) {
          return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
      });
  }

  function handleData(info) {
    console.log(info);
    setAni_list_info(info);
  }

  function handleError(error) {
      alert('Error, check console');
      console.error(error);
  }
}, []);
return (
<>...</>
}
```

Comment: Set state is asynchronous stop using it as a way to communicate between lines of code. It does not work like updating an object property. I would suggest this: remove the `variables` state and the `anime_chan_data` state completely. Move your fetching logic into a single effect that does both requests after another and at the end updates `ani_list_info`.

Comment: @Herku I did what you suggested, removing variables state and anime-chan_data state then I used normal javascript variable `var variables = { search: 'lelouch'}` and fetching two API's one after another in one useEffect. after fetching 1st API I updated `search` variable but still it is showing the default query result.
Still `search` variable is not updating

Comment: @Herku Did I am missing something about GraphQL variables and how to use them in Reactjs.
And Thank you for your response

Comment: I think you don't understand how closures and react state work. I will maybe create a sondbox in a bit to show you what I mean. It's hard without a working environment.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-surf-21yhe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You should probably only track things in state that you need for rendering. Keep as little things in React state. React state is not a good way to communicate between functions or effects. In general, the closure is not a place for communicating between functions.

Comment: @Herku Thank you for all your efforts. It worked. I will definitely work on my React.js skills

Comment: React is complicated and hooks make this even less easy to see through. I think a good exercise would be to understand why your first solution doesn't work. Think about the render cycles and what the variables are in which cycle.